# Foreach loop on windows command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line

I have a command line which copies files from folder A to folder B:

```
copy A\* B\
```

I would now like to delete all files in B that are present in A, non-recursively.  I can list the files in A like this:

```
dir /b /a-d A
```

With the output being:

```
f0.txt
f1.txt
f2.txt
```

Here is the pseudocode for what I would like to do:

```
foreach $1 in <dir /b /a-d A output>:
  del B\$1
```

Is there a windows command-line syntax that will execute a command, using the output of another command as an input?  I am aware of the piping operator ( | ) but do not know of a way that this could be used to accomplish this task.  Any help would be appreciate.

Restriction: Only commands available by default in Windows 7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can iterate over files with

```
for %x in (*) do ...
```

which is also a lot more robust than trying to iterate over the output of a command for this use case.

So

```
for %f in (A\*) do del "B\%~nxf"
```

or, if you need this in a batch file instead of the command line:

```
for %%f in (A\*) do del "B\%%~nxf"
```

`%~nxf` returns only the file name and extension of each file since it will be prefixed with `A\` and you want to delete it in B.

Add `> nul 2>&1` to suppress any output (error messages may appear when you try deleting files that don't exist).

---

Just for completeness, you can in fact iterate over the output of a command in almost the same way:

```
for /f %x in ('some command') do ...
```

but there are several problems with doing this and in the case of iterating over `dir` output it's rarely necessary, hence I don't recommend it.

---

And since you are on Windows 7, you have PowerShell as well:

```
Get-ChildItem A\* | ForEach-Object { Remove-Item ('B\' + $_.Name) }
```

or shorter:

```
ls A\* | % { rm B\$($_.Name) }
```

Comment: you could add `-erroraction Silentlycontinue` to avoid the errors when some file in A don't exist in B

Comment: Suppose I have a long list, how can I split the long line of elements in it? Example: `FOR %%G IN (11288211,38948621) DO ( )`

Comment: for /f %x in ('cmd /c "git branch | grep ^DE"') do echo %x - example for iterating over advance filtered list (top hit in google/bing). (where git is installed with option to include grep & other posix utils in file path). The pipe "|" in the command was difficult to get working.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F %f IN ('dir /b /a-d A') DO del B\$f
```